# Añadir campo contraseña en el registro de Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Buenos días a todos! Estoy creando una Web en Wordpress y me gustaría saber cómo puedo añadir un campo de contraseña en el registro para que los usuarios puedan establecer su contraseña durante el registro y quitar la opción de que te envíen un correo con tu contraseña.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Este plugin es para aprobar los usuarios que se registran en tu web, (https://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/) este plugin te permitirá configurar esa opción o bien en las opciones o bien en el código modificando esa opción.

Answer (score 0):

Para esta funcionalidad debes de tener instalado **WooCommerce** e ir a las *configuraciones* de **WooCommerce** y en el apartado de *cuentas y privacidad*, debes desactivar la opcion que dice cuando se crea una cuenta enviar un enlace al nuevo usuario para crear la contraseña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]